# Using BigDecimal to validate epoch timestamp in exponential notation

Tags: java, performance, datetime, validation

I have some phone records in which epoch time is coming in exponential format like 1467.738871E9. I need to validate those records in which number is not in proper format and drop those records. Right now, I am using big decimal, but I have heard that bigdecimal is slow and takes more space. Since I have million of records to be validated, is there any other way to validate time which is more space- and time-efficient?

```
try{
    new BigDecimal(data).toBigInteger();}
    catch(NumberFormatException n){
      return false;
    } 
return true;
```

Examples of valid timestamps:

- 1.467983982E9
- 1.468119771E9
- 1467858808E9
- 1.468119771E11
- 1468119771E11

Examples of invalid timestamps:

- 1.46A802215E9
- null
- 4.1B46A802215E9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point in calling `toBigInteger` since that doesn't throw anything. You might as well just have this:

```
try {
    new BigDecimal(data);
} catch(NumberFormatException n) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Or you might consider using `toBigIntegerExact` if you don't allow fractional parts in the number (e.g. 1.2345E3 which is 1234.5 is not allowed):

```
try {
    new BigDecimal(data).toBigIntegerExact();
} catch(NumberFormatException | ArithmeticException e) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Also, have you thought about whether negative numbers should be allowed?

Regarding time & space performance, it will create one BigDecimal object (and possibly one BigInteger object) for every valid record. It will then release it as eligible for garbage collection. The JIT compiler will probably optimize this to make it insignificant compared to the time it takes to read and write the records.

Comment: ToBigInteger is needed because  for this 1.23456789754E12 System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.23456789754E12"));Output is 1.23456789754E+12 which is not valid epoch time and for below
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.23456789754E12").toBigInteger()); Output is 1234567897540 which is valid epoch time

Comment: I have read that bigdecimal uses more space and time,is there any other  way to handle this

Comment: Yes, but your code is not doing a System.out.println. It is only creating a BigDecimal and then a BigInteger and immediately throwing both away. So, what's the point of creating a BigInteger and then throwing it away? Might as well not create it.

Comment: yes,but with bigdecimal 1.2679876E5 is also valid,I think as you mentioned its better to use integerExact.

Comment: -Will bigdecimal and integerExact will impact performance if I have to process millions of records.

Comment: The best way is to measure the performance impact yourself. Try it with a subset of your data - say the first 100 thousand records. Use this method and then compare it with a dummy method that has a trivial (very fast) implementation, e.g. one that returns true 95% of the time and false once every 20 calls. Then compare the timings between the two. I think you will find very little difference. To improve performance, look at the implementation of the constructor `BigDecimal(String)` and copy the code that parses the string and leave out the code that creates the object which you don't need.